# How to foreach loop data in Controller using addonisjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

How to foreach data and update data in loop using adonisjs  I wannt to do something like this

in php I do this

```
$emp = Employee::all()

foreach($emp as $data) {
 $emp_store = Store::where('emp_id', $emp->id);
 $emp_store->name = $emp_name;
 $emp->save()
}
```

but after I change into adonisjs How can I do something like this in Controller . Now I try to do

```
const emp =  await Employee.all();
    for(var val of emp) {
     // I want to update data using each emp id
      console.log(val)
    }
```

after I try to do I got an error said `emp is not iterable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just find it

```
for(let i in emp.rows) {
      const lobby = emp.rows[i]
      console.log(lobby) // you should be able to have access to name now
}
```

thnks

Answer (score 0):

> To convert a serializable instance to a plain array/object, call its toJSON method:

```
const json = emp.toJSON()
```

With this you can loop through the array